# How I can output in same line java

Tags: java, switch-statement

So far I done all the code. it can run and also I can get my output. But I only can get different line output , I want get output in same line. There have any way to do that . I use switch case , can I do it with switch case or any other statement can output that.

```
public class practice
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String name="Farhana Konka";
        String initials= "";
        for(String s: name.split(" "))
        {
            initials+=s.charAt(0);
        }

        char[] myInitials=initials.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<myInitials.length; i++)
        {
            switch(myInitials[i])
            {
            case 'f' :
            case 'F' :

                System.out.println("FFFFF ");
                System.out.println("F     ");
                System.out.println("F     ");
                System.out.println("FFF   ");
                System.out.println("F     ");
                System.out.println("F     ");
                System.out.println("F     ");
                break;
            case 'K' :
            case 'k' :

                System.out.println("K   K ");
                System.out.println("K  K  ");
                System.out.println("K K   ");
                System.out.println("KK    ");
                System.out.println("K K   ");
                System.out.println("K  K  ");
                System.out.println("K   K ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Nothing happen");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It showing output in different line. But i want it on same line . Something like below But I am getting output only different line. How I can change my code to do that. I try but I failed to do it.
[image]

Comment: `println()` vs `print()` ?

Comment: you came back in December and never accepted any answers...

Answer (score 3):

You need to be way smarter than just processing every letter individually. You would need to process all of the letters for each line! Because you cannot modify the line's content retroactively.

So instead of just a mere case-switch, you need to store the individual lines in arrays for each letter, then process the initials for the first line, enter new line, process the initials for the second line, enter new line, and so on.

In order to write into the same line, you need to use `System.out.print()` but that in itself will not solve your problem.

EDIT:

Well I put my version together based on what I said, and it prints me this:

```
FFFFFF   AA   RRRRR  H    H   AA   N    N   AA      K    K  OOOO  N    N K    K   AA   
F       A  A  R    R H    H  A  A  NN   N  A  A     K  K   O    O NN   N K  K    A  A  
F      A    A RRRRR  HHHHHH A    A N N  N A    A    KK     O    O N N  N KK     A    A 
FFFF   AAAAAA R  R   H    H AAAAAA N  N N AAAAAA    K K    O    O N  N N K K    AAAAAA 
F      A    A R   R  H    H A    A N   NN A    A    K  K   O    O N   NN K  K   A    A 
F      A    A R    R H    H A    A N    N A    A    K    K  OOOO  N    N K    K A    A
```

And the magic line was this:

```
Map<Character, List<String>> charMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Although this *can* be done with mere String arrays, but this was easier.

Good luck with your assignment.

EDIT2: 
I hate assignments that limit you in how you can do them just so you can write worse code.

```
    Map<Character, List<String>> charMap = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> listSpace = new ArrayList<>();
    listSpace.add("  ");
    listSpace.add("  ");
    listSpace.add("  ");
    listSpace.add("  ");
    listSpace.add("  ");
    listSpace.add("  ");
    charMap.put(' ', listSpace);


    List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add("  AA  ");
    listA.add(" A  A ");
    listA.add("A    A");
    listA.add("AAAAAA");
    listA.add("A    A");
    listA.add("A    A");
    charMap.put('a', listA);

    List<String> listF = new ArrayList<>();
    listF.add("FFFFFF");
    listF.add("F     ");
    listF.add("F     ");
    listF.add("FFFF  ");
    listF.add("F     ");
    listF.add("F     ");
    charMap.put('f', listF);

    List<String> listR = new ArrayList<>();
    listR.add("RRRRR ");
    listR.add("R    R");
    listR.add("RRRRR ");
    listR.add("R  R  ");
    listR.add("R   R ");
    listR.add("R    R");
    charMap.put('r', listR);

    List<String> listH = new ArrayList<>();
    listH.add("H    H");
    listH.add("H    H");
    listH.add("HHHHHH");
    listH.add("H    H");
    listH.add("H    H");
    listH.add("H    H");
    charMap.put('h', listH);

    List<String> listK = new ArrayList<>();
    listK.add("K    K");
    listK.add("K  K  ");
    listK.add("KK    ");
    listK.add("K K   ");
    listK.add("K  K  ");
    listK.add("K    K");
    charMap.put('k', listK);

    List<String> listN = new ArrayList<>();
    listN.add("N    N");
    listN.add("NN   N");
    listN.add("N N  N");
    listN.add("N  N N");
    listN.add("N   NN");
    listN.add("N    N");
    charMap.put('n', listN);

    List<String> listO = new ArrayList<>();
    listO.add(" OOOO ");
    listO.add("O    O");
    listO.add("O    O");
    listO.add("O    O");
    listO.add("O    O");
    listO.add(" OOOO ");
    charMap.put('o', listO);

    for(int lineCount = 0; lineCount < 6; lineCount++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
        {
            Character c = name.charAt(i);
            List<String> lineList = charMap.get(c);
            String currentLine = lineList.get(lineCount);
            System.out.print("" + currentLine);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

And now I wrote this:

```
    String[] arraySpace = new String[]
    {
        "  ",
        "  ",
        "  ",
        "  ",
        "  ",
        "  "
    };

    String[] arrayA = new String[]
    {
        "  AA  ",
        " A  A ",
        "A    A",
        "AAAAAA",
        "A    A",
        "A    A"            
    };

    String[] arrayF = new String[]
    {
        "FFFFFF",
        "F     ",
        "F     ",
        "FFFF  ",
        "F     ",
        "F     " 
    };

    String[] arrayR = new String[]
    {
        "RRRRR ",
        "R    R",
        "RRRRR ",
        "R  R  ",
        "R   R ",
        "R    R"    
    };

    String[] arrayH = new String[]
    {
        "H    H",
        "H    H",
        "HHHHHH",
        "H    H",
        "H    H",
        "H    H"
    };

    String[] arrayK = new String[]
    {
        "K    K",
        "K  K  ",
        "KK    ",
        "K K   ",
        "K  K  ",
        "K    K"        
    };

    String[] arrayN = new String[]
    {
        "N    N",
        "NN   N",
        "N N  N",
        "N  N N",
        "N   NN",
        "N    N"
    };

    String[] arrayO = new String[]
    {
        " OOOO ",
        "O    O",
        "O    O",
        "O    O",
        "O    O",
        " OOOO "
    };

    String name = "farhana konka";
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
        {
            switch(name.charAt(i))
            {
                case 'a':
                    System.out.print(arrayA[j]);
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    System.out.print(arrayF[j]);
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    System.out.print(arrayR[j]);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    System.out.print(arrayN[j]);
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    System.out.print(arrayO[j]);
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    System.out.print(arrayK[j]);
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    System.out.print(arraySpace[j]);
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    System.out.print(arrayH[j]);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FFFFFF    AA    RRRRR   H    H    AA    N    N    AA        K    K   OOOO   N    N  K    K    AA    
F        A  A   R    R  H    H   A  A   NN   N   A  A       K  K    O    O  NN   N  K  K     A  A   
F       A    A  RRRRR   HHHHHH  A    A  N N  N  A    A      KK      O    O  N N  N  KK      A    A  
FFFF    AAAAAA  R  R    H    H  AAAAAA  N  N N  AAAAAA      K K     O    O  N  N N  K K     AAAAAA  
F       A    A  R   R   H    H  A    A  N   NN  A    A      K  K    O    O  N   NN  K  K    A    A  
F       A    A  R    R  H    H  A    A  N    N  A    A      K    K   OOOO   N    N  K    K  A    A
```

Switch-case, yay! It does exactly the same thing, except now I need to do something manually that I was doing automatically (indexing the arrays by the character in a map). How silly.

Comment: Sorry , it is not the solution, if I used print , I can not get the  my format for a , b ,I also know we have to use System.out.print()

Comment: You did not read the first and second paragraph, and that is **not** my fault.

Comment: Actually I have to use switch case then need to output in same line. Must we have to use switch case, This way I also can do easily,

Comment: so can you use arrays or not?

Comment: I did not code the 26 letters, but you can if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

use Print instead of Println

```
System.out.print("your message");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `System.out.print` whenever you need to print to same line since it does not contain a carriage return at the end of the printed text. If you need to do a carriage return after the text you have to use `System.out.println`